# get the greatest date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the data as follow

```
id    date             item bought
1     2011-12-12        car
1     2011-11-10        bus
1     2010-12-15        van
```

In this query how can I find the the greatest date result? Please can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(Date) AS GreatestDate
FROM table
```

To get the record(s) with the max date:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM YourTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
SELECT MAX([date]) FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY
date DESC
```